# call multiple powershell scripts from a single powershell script

Tags: powershell

How to call multiple powershell scripts from a single powershell script?

I have this from web search -

file "FolderWatcherMain.ps1" contains code:

```
$ExternalMethod = "D:\a\FolderWatcher1.ps1"
.$ExternalMethod
$ExternalMethod = "D:\a\FolderWatcher2.ps1"
.$ExternalMethod
```

This isn't working. Any suggestions from dear members.  Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "This isn't working" part - what isn't working? What did you expect? What behavior/errors/output did you observe to the contrary?

Comment: Adding more details than : "This isn't working" might help. Launching from a single files multiple PS scripts should work:
."myscript.ps1"
."myotherscript.ps1" 
Maybe, there is some helpful output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like this

```
$PSScriptRoot="D:\a"
    $ExternalMethod = $PSScriptRoot + ".\FolderWatcher1.ps1"

    .$ExternalMethod

    $ExternalMethod = $PSScriptRoot + ".\FolderWatcher2.ps1"

    .$ExternalMethod
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the path to the PS script in a string variable use the `&` operator to access it like:

```
$ExternalMethod = "D:\a\FolderWatcher1.ps1"
& $ExternalMethod
```

Or you could use `Start-Process` and that would give the the `-Wait` parameter if you needed it:

```
$ExternalMethod = "D:\a\FolderWatcher1.ps1"
Start-Process PowerShell -Argument $ExternalMethod -Wait
```